# Windows Command Prompt - Getting new interface

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, user-interface

Recently getting back into the swing of using Windows command prompt for doing stuff, and for some reason the text on my command prompt is really small and tough to read. I was wondering if anyone knows how to manipulate font size for command prompt so that I can actually read stuff easier, or if I can replace the current UI with something more user-friendly.

**Small note:** I use 2 monitors. One is my laptop's which is 1366x768 and the other is 1920x1080. When CMD is on the 1920x1080 monitor, is when the font is really tiny and tough to read. Could the problem be that CMD opens in a resolution fit for the original monitor?

Comment: I recommend Conemu, it has several skins and very customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Run `cmd` then look on the top left corner of window, it is a black icon with something like "C:\", when you spot it, make a right click on it and choose "Properties", in a new window that will appear - switch to the "Font" tab and increase font size as you like it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a YouTube video outlining your problem.  Based on its rating it should prove helpful!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWxD0QzhmUg

Basically you right click on the top of the command prompt/window and go to properties.  From there find the necessary setting to change font size and anything else that you would like to change!

**Note: You can further research little hacks, quirks if interested.  One I know of is changing the background and font colour!**

You can also do this via the registry editor.
If you are unfamiliar with editing the registry, make sure you backup your registry before attempting any changes.

**To Backup Registry:  https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-back-up-the-windows-registry-2625146**

Use this site for helpful information in general and regarding your question..pictures provided make it very user friendly.

I can only post one link, but it is called HowToGeek.

You can also edit the font to be something more readable, preferable a la your user preference.

Here is the remaining extension..search it on Google:

stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/

Cheers.

Comment: .....never in all my days did it occur to me that right clicking on the top of the window would do anything...

Comment: The more you know :)

Comment: @Adrian : In this particular case, the menu that pops up is the same menu as if you left-click the icon in the upper-left corner, which is a standard dating back to at least the early 1990s (20+ years ago), even before right-clicking was commonly used for menus.